# "dockerfile" text file busy

Tags: docker, makefile, dockerfile

I want to create a project from dockerfile. Firstly, I should clone a framework from github and install it.
In my `Dockerfile` I have the following instrutions:

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/simgrid/project.git
WORKDIR "/project"
RUN cmake option1 options2 .
RUN sudo make
RUN sudo make install
```

I build image with:

```
docker build -t "myimage" .
```

But I have an error about `text file busy`. How can I overcome it?

```
    make[2]: execvp: /simgrid/tools/sg_unit_extractor.pl: Text file busy
    make[2]: *** [src/cunit_unit.cpp] Error 127
    CMakeFiles/testall.dir/build.make:69: recipe for target 'src/cunit_unit.cpp' failed
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:616: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/testall.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/testall.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    The command '/bin/sh -c sudo make' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

My Dockerfile content is:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
            sudo \
            git \
            build-essential \ 
            cmake \
            libboost-dev \
            libboost-all-dev \
            doxygen \
            python3
RUN git clone https://github.com/simgrid/simgrid.git
WORKDIR "/simgrid"
RUN cmake -Denable_documentation=OFF -Denable_coverage=OFF -Denable_java=OFF -Denable_model-checking=OFF \
    -Denable_lua=OFF -Denable_compile_optimizations=OFF -Denable_smpi=OFF -Denable_smpi_MPICH3_testsuite=OFF -Denable_compile_warnings=OFF .
RUN sudo make 
RUN sudo make install
```

Comment: Please include enough detail to reproduce your problem. E.g. a full Dockerfile and a valid public git repo.

Comment: @BMitch Here my dockerfile https://github.com/kenenbek/travisci/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Please do *not* link to an external resource (in your case, the Dockerfile). Post a *complete minimal* example instead (see also [MCVE]).

Comment: I've been running a build of your dockerfile for the past 10 minutes or so, it's currently fetching package 250 as part of your apt-get command. Something more minimal to reproduce your problem would be appreciated.

Comment: @BMitch uhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: Generally, this means that an executable (the "text file" phrase is misleading) is trying to be executed while it's also being modified in-place ("in-place" is important: the right way to modify an executable is to write a new version and replace the old filename entry to point to the new one, which is an atomic operation that leaves the inode with the old copy of the executable intact until its reference count reaches zero, and is thus not vulnerable to this error). But figuring out the details depends on, well, details.

Comment: This would happen if, for instance, `sg_unit_extractor.pl` had a `#!/usr/bin/perl` shebang, but something was writing to `/usr/bin/perl` (or a shared library that `perl` depends on) while it was trying to execute.

Answer (score 3):

The error message you are seeing is from the output of make. It does not appear be an error for Docker. Instead, this points back to the code being compiled inside the image and so you would want to raise this issue with them in github.

I do see a fair number of kernel and network components being compiled with the app, which may not properly function in a docker sandbox, and so the code you are trying to compile may not be able to run in this type of isolation without disabling some of the protections that docker provides. See [docker's security documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/) for more details, particularly on the namespaces, cgroups, and capabilities to protect the kernel.

Comment: Sometimes I see this error and sometimes I don't when I build an image. It's very strange. Did you get that error?

Comment: I didn't get the error running make from inside the container (leaving cmake as last instruction in Dockerfile). Depending on your need, you could commit the image after that, even if it's absolutely not clean practice.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this is not a Docker issue there are some scenarios where you can face this error building a dockerfile.
Just to bring a known workaround (even if it is not the most elegant solution) let me show you this one.

In my case I got the message " Text file busy " when trying to build a Dockerfile with the following line:

```
RUN chmod 500 /build/build_dotcms.sh && /build/build_dotcms.sh ${BUILD_FROM} ${BUILD_ID}
```

Provoked an interruption with "Text file busy" intermitently.

The workaround was to add a "sleep 1" between chmod command and shell script execution

```
RUN chmod 500 /build/build_dotcms.sh && sleep 1 && /build/build_dotcms.sh ${BUILD_FROM} ${BUILD_ID}
```

I found the solution in a github thread: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9547

Hope it helps.